# Different colors and ripples on the mobile devices in three.js scene

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with displaying three.js scene on mobile devices. Image become more blurred this little another colours and ripples

For example on this page
https://site3d.site/project/bar

Desktop - http://prntscr.com/1jqhyvv
Mobile - http://prntscr.com/1jqilkv

Answer (score 0):

When creating a 3D Scene you must remember of setting correct renderer's pixel ratio and size.

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: I do this, resolution is good but colours are not and there are ripples